# Sprite not moving despite inputs in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I'm facing a problem in pygame where the sprite is not moving regardless the inputs, i've checked it several times but have no clue what's wrong with it. There are 3 pages, first contains the main loop of the game, second contains the code of player sprite and third contains some game functions.

main---------page-01

```
import pygame
import sys
from player import Player
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    # Intialise the game and start the screen
    pygame.init()   
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    pygame.display.set_caption("AmarCreep")
    
    player = Player(screen)
    
    # Main loop
    while True:
        # Check if user wants to quit
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
                
        # Navy screen       
        screen.fill((0,0,128))
        
        gf.responses(screen, player)
        player.p_movements()
            
        # Make the player appear
        player.draw_player()
        
        # Make the newly made screen visible
        pygame.display.flip()
    
run_game()
```

Player--------------------page-02

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite


class Player(Sprite):
    # Initialise the main player
    
    def __init__(self, screen):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        
        # Specifying the position of the player at start 
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 30, 30)
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = 590
        
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_up = False
        
    def p_movements(self):
        
        if self.moving_left:
            self.rect.x -= 5
        if self.moving_right:
            self.rect.x += 5
        if self.moving_up:
            self.rect.y -= 30   
        
    def draw_player(self):
        ''' Draw the player on the screen'''
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (255,255,255), self.rect)
```

game_functions------------------page-03

```
import pygame


def responses(screen, player):
    ''' Check for responses'''
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.moving_up == True
                
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.moving_left == True
                
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.moving_right == True
                
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.moving_up == False
                
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.moving_left == False
                
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.moving_right == False
```

Answer (score 1):

The *first* thing you appear to do in your main event loop is to totally clear the queue while looking for a quit event. That's not going to necessarily go down well with your second event loop in the game functions file.

In fact, it's quite messy to have two event loops, one of which throws away anything that's not a quit event - this may well lead to lost events.

I suspect a better way would be to provide a `response` game function which just handles *one* event (and doesn't touch the event queue at all):

```py
def response(screen, player, evt):
    if evt.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        blah blah blah
```

and have the main (now the *only*) event loop call that for events it does not want to handle itself:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()
    gf.response(screen, player, event)
```

---

You may also want to consider what you would expect when both the up and down button are pressed (or the left and right, for that matter). At a minimum, you probably want to make that a test case :-)

Comment: sorry to said it again but sprite is still not moving

Comment: I was still checking my code and got that little mistake due to which it wasnt running, but thank you so much @paxdiablo for helping